# Citing Blogposts from official governing authorities

Tags: citations, conference

I am revising a conference paper and I in fact have a blogpost from the European Commission. The [Post](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-single-market/en/blogposts/business-business-platforms-race-europe-cannot-afford-lose) mentions about about Business-to-Business Platforms and Europe's involvement.

A reviewer mentioned this explicitly that

> there is a blogpost cited which is seen as a shortcoming for the literature review.

But the post has some relevant information for the paper since one aspect of the theme ponders upon the B2B platform development opportunities in Europe and current progress.

I have cited it as following:

> Lemke, M.: European Commission. Available Online: https://ec.europa.eu/digital-single-market/en/blogposts/business-business-platforms-race-europe-cannot-afford-lose, last accessed 2019-03-02

But I wish to obtain some insight as to how such relevant blogposts can be used within Academia. There are many examples where the European Commission provides statistics and data regarding different strata of research.

How do I inculcate the information within the paper?

Comment: Unless you are citing it for the fact that Max Lemke said something in a blog post, it seems like anything you would cite from there would be available in a more official publication.

Answer (score 1):

You can cite blog-posts, and whatever citation style you are using will explain the right format. Citation styles are written to be all-encompassing, not just for citing papers. I suggest including an archive link of the page, because blog posts can easily disappear from the internet and then the citation becomes invalid. I actually saw a case where the person cited an article and a few weeks later it was gone, I couldn't even find it by googling.

Keep in mind that blogs are not peer reviewed, and are not afforded the same authority on facts that papers would be. So you should be careful about using the blog as support for your claims. Generally, taking what is said in a blog post at face value and accepting it as fact would be foolish in an academic text. People can write anything they please in their blog, it doesn't make it true. However, the fact that a person has chosen to write that, is a fact. That fact may be interesting by itself. For example, if a senior official claims a certain thing, they may or may not be right, but the fact that they claim it is enough to suspect that they will try to exert their influence to make the claim true. That part is significant.

In the text I would also make it clear that you are talking about a non-peer reviewed source, instead of simply citing it as you would a paper. I find it very annoying when you see a very interesting and cited claim, excitedly go to the reference list, only to discover that the citation is really just some blog so the claim is effectively pulled out of thin air - the citation only proves that the pulling was done by a third party, rather than the citing author.